# using queryselector to select something from a innerhtml inside a component from the main javascript file

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I'm finishing a school project but I ran into a problem. I got the feeling it's just something really simple that I just forgot. But I need to add 4 faq question and answers. But right now it is adding 4 separate sections instead of 1 section with the 4 faq question and answers.

Index file

```
import Component from "../components/Component.js";
import QuestionComponent from "../components/QuestionComponent.js";


window.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
    let index = new IndexController();
    index.init();
});

class IndexController {

    init() {

        let questions = [{
            question: 'vraag1',
            answer: 'antwoord1'
        }, {
            question: 'vraag2',
            answer: 'antwoord2'
        }, {
            question: 'vraag3',
            answer: 'antwoord3'
        }, {
            question: 'vraag4',
            answer: 'antwoord4'
        }
        ];

        for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
            const q = questions[i];
            const question = this.rootElement;
            this.qComponent = new QuestionComponent(q.question, q.answer);
            // Voeg vervolgens de qComponent toe aan de section  
            document.querySelector('main"]').append(this.qComponent.getView());
        }
    }
}
```

It kind of only is about the last line because I probably just need something else instead of document.

Component File

```
import Component from "./Component.js"

export default class QuestionComponent extends Component {

    constructor(question, answer) {
        super("section");
        this.rootElement.id = "faq";
        this.rootElement.classList.add("faqSection");

        this.vraag = question;
        this.antwoord = answer;

        this.initView(this.vraag, this.antwoord);
    }


    initView() {
        this.rootElement.innerHTML = `
            <h2>FAQ Component</h2>
            <div class="faqComponent">
                <p class="firstQuestion question">${this.vraag}</p>
                <p class="firstAnswer">${this.antwoord}</p>
            </div>`;



        let el = this.querySelector('question');
        el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            this.onClick(event)
        });

    }

    onClick() {
        console.log("onClick functie wordt aangeroepen.");

        let answer = this.querySelector('firstAnswer');
        answer.classList.toggle('hidden');
    }
}
```

could probably also be something wrong with this so I thought I'd just include it so you can understand it better I guess.

Comment: `.querySelector()` needs a CSS selector so if it;s a className prefix it with a dot `.`, if it's an id prefix it with a hash `#`. The only time you don't prefix a selector is a tagName `div`, `span`, etc. You have for example `question` and there's no such thing as `<question>` element.

Comment: Im sorry i had some old testing code into that one. Can you check again? So with this code with me using "main" it just gives me 4 different sections with the 2 strings on each section from the array. But i want all 8 strings in 1 section.

Comment: Note that in English, the word is "I'm" when you mean "I am", not "Im". We also capitalize the letter I when referring to ourselves.

Comment: You're pretty close, but if I'm looking at this right, you are creating a new section for every instance of the QA component, then looping over that creation process 4 times, giving you those 4 sections instead of 1. Instead of creating the section and the H2 element in each instance of the QA  component, you can append those elements to "main" once, then in your loop, select the section inside main  ("main section") and append your div element that contains the question and answer pair.

Comment: Thanks i can already make progress with that. But I am kinda struggling with selecting that div element from the index file. So with what should i need to replace that document.querySelector, or could you maybe rewrite that line for me. That would be great, thanks.

Comment: Not sure how the Component.js file works, can you include that? Also, check for a typo: querySelector('main"]') to querySelector('main'). For QA component file, if super("section") creates a <section> element, then you need to replace that with the div element from initView(). Something like super("div"), & update the class & id accordingly. You can leave the section tag out & append the divs directly to the main element, or if you include section, change:  querySelector("main") to querySelector("main section"). Just be sure to append <section> with <h2> to <main> outside of the loop.

Comment: I need more context to write out a proper answer, but for clarity, if "main" is not the <main> element, but rather a class name or id of a <div> element, then refer to the first comment by @zer00ne that explains how to select by id or class name using querySelector()

Comment: Hey, because of you saying that thing of changing the section to div my brain started working. So i changed section to div and changed the class name. After that i changed the queryselector to section. And now it works completely like i wanted. Thanks for the help, i really appreciate it.